# Error: assignment to expression with array type while using selection-sort

Tags: c, arrays, struct, error-handling, selection-sort

Basically, I'm trying to `sort` an agenda with 3 names using `selection sort` method. Pretty sure the selection sort part is OK. The problem is that apparently my code can identify the [0] chars of the string, but cannot pass one string to another variable. Here is my code:

```
include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[25];
} NAME;

int main(){

    int a, b;
    char x, y[25];

    static NAME names[]={
        {"Zumbazukiba"},
        {"Ademiro"},
        {"Haroldo Costa"}
    };

    for(a=0; a<4; a++){

        x = names[a].name[0];
        y = names[a];

        for(b=(a-1); b>=0 && x<(names[b].name[0]); b--){
            names[b+1] = names[b];
        }
        names[b+1].name = y;
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error message:

> main.c:21:11: error: assignment to expression with array type
>            y = names[a];

Comment: Because you are trying to assign to arrays like that. use this one `y[a] = names[a]`

Answer (score 1):

There are *at least* two errors in your code, in the line flagged by your compiler. First, you can't copy character strings (or, indeed, any other array type) using the simple assignment (`=`) operator in `C` - you need to use the [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) function (which requires a `#include <string.h>` line in your code).

Second, you have declared `y` as a character array (`char y[25]`) but `names` is an array of `NAME` **structures**; presumably, you want to copy the `name` field of the given structure into `y`.

So, instead of:

```c
y = names[a];
```

you should use:

```
strcpy(y, names[a].name);
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For starters I do not see the selection sort. It seems you mean the insertion sort.

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. So statements like this

```
names[b+1].name = y;
```

where you are trying to assign an array are invalid.

And  in statements like this

```
y = names[a];
```

you are trying to assign an object of the structure type to a character array.

Moreover the loops are also incorrect.

The array has only 3 elements. So it it is unclear what the magic number 4 is doing in this loop

```
for(a=0; a<4; a++){
```

and this loop

```
for(b=(a-1); b>=0 && x<(names[b].name[0]); b--){
```

skips the first iteration when a is equal to 0.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the selection sort can be applyed to elements of your array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH  25

typedef struct
{
    char name[LENGTH];
} NAME;

int main(void) 
{
    NAME names[] =
    {
        { "Zumbazukiba" },
        { "Ademiro" },
        { "Haroldo Costa" }
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( names ) / sizeof( *names );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        puts( names[i].name );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t min = i;

        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++ )
        {
            if ( strcmp( names[j].name, names[min].name ) < 0 )
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        if ( i != min )
        {
            NAME tmp = names[i];
            names[i] = names[min];
            names[min] = tmp;
        }
    }


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        puts( names[i].name );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Zumbazukiba
Ademiro
Haroldo Costa

Ademiro
Haroldo Costa
Zumbazukiba
```